# Converting sql data to json but json file include recordset

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, json, reactjs

I'm trying to convert sql data to json data but when file is completed I get something 'recordset' what is this and how do i get rid of it.

```
  app.post("/Employees",function (req, res)  {
           const sql = require("mssql");
    
           const config = {
          
            server: 'HOST',  //update me
            user: 'user', //update me
            password: 'pass',  //update me
            database: 'db',
            trustServerCertificate: true
           }
    
           // var to store file name 
           var d = new Date();
             var fileName = "db_"+d.getDate()+"_"+d.getMonth()+"_"+d.getTime();
           sql.connect(config, function(err, data) {
            
             if(err) console.log(err);
               let sqlRequest = new sql.Request();
    
               let sqlQuery = "select * from dbo.cust where name like 'aa%' AND surname like 'a%' AND branch='bsmtr';";
               sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, function (err, data) {
                 if(err) console.log(err) 
                 console.log(data);
               
                 fs.writeFile(`json_files/${fileName}.json`, JSON.stringify(data, replacer, space), err => err && console.log(err));
                 sql.close();
               });
           });
          
           res.send("The JSON file is downloaded please find it in the Json directory by the name "+fileName+".JSON");
        });
```

-----This is how I am getting the json .---

```
{
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "rowno": 294680503,
                "rowno_custcrm_crm": 0,
                "has_custansp_ansp": 0,
                "rowno_custemt_emt": 0,
                "rowno_custmtm_mtm": 0,
                "rowno_custm2mc_m2mcu": 0,
                "has_custext_ext": 0,
                "rowno_custcloa_cloa": 0,
                "has_custalrt_alrt": 0,
                "rowno_custemcc_emcc": 0,
                "rowno_custiop_iop": 0,
                "has_custcds_cds": 0,
                "has_custltv_ltv": 0,
                "rowno_custoir_oir": 0,
                "rowno_custorcc_orcc": 0,
                "rowno_custcmps_cmps": 0
            }
        ]
    ],
   
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": 1
}
```

Please tell me how i get rid of recordset, square brackets and output and rowsafftectd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just need to stringify the data you actually want to put into a file. e.g. if you want the content of the `recordset` you need to call `JSON.stringify(data.recordset, replacer, space)`. If you want to put that one element that you have in the `recordset` you need to use `JSON.stringify(data.recordsets[0][0], replacer, space)`

Comment: It worked but I'm still getting the square brackets. How do I get rid of that? Thank you.

Comment: Square brackets mean that you are saving an array. Just take one more element deep.